# Trie implementation in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, trie

So I have an assignment for school, that needs me (among other stuff) to create a trie, in order to use it to store some numbers and the times each path is being used. For example, if I insert "1234" and then "1255", nodes of 1 and 2 should have a value=2 while nodes of 3 and 4 should have a value=1.

Problem is, I don't know how to implement such a trie in Prolog (i'm quite a begginer).
I found this code [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/55-prolog/59e7d719f1e1d18f.htm):

```erlang
:- use_module(library(lists)).
new_trie(root-[]). 

%%% Add a string to the trie. 

% We have reached a word ending, so this must be a terminal node. 
extend_trie([], TrieIn, TrieOut) :- 
        ensure_terminal(TrieIn, TrieOut). 
% If we have a node for C here, we need to extend it with Cs. 
extend_trie([C | Cs], Char-Children, Char-[NewChild | OtherChildren]) :- 
        select(C-CChildren, Children, OtherChildren), 
        !, 
        extend_trie(Cs, C-CChildren, NewChild). 
% There is no C node, so we need to construct a new one. 
extend_trie([C | Cs], Char-Children, Char-[NewChild | Children]) :- 
        extend_trie(Cs, C-[], NewChild). 
% A terminal node is one with the 'terminal' child. 
ensure_terminal(Char-Children, Char-Children) :- 
        member(terminal, Children), 
        !. 
ensure_terminal(Char-Children, Char-[terminal | Children]). 
%%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
%%% Decide whether or not a word occupies the trie. 
%%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% If we've got to the end of our string, it is a word if there is a terminal child. 
lookup_trie([], _Char-Children) :- 
        member(terminal, Children). 
% If we have more characters in our string, lookup the C trie and continue. 
lookup_trie([C | Cs], _Char-Children) :- 
        member(C-GrandChildren, Children), 
        lookup_trie(Cs, C-GrandChildren).
```

But I don't know how to use this. I mean I don't know how to create a trie with this, or insert/lookup values.

Any help or advice?

Comment: do you know *what* a trie is? have you tried reading Wikipedia?  copying someone else's code is not a good way to learn a language, better to try writing something yourself. you'll learn more that way. Usually in Prolog writing down what a thing *is* gives us a program to manipulate it, for free. Start small, write down what is a trie created from an empty word; then from a one-letter word; and proceed from there.

Comment: @WillNess I've already written the same program in SMLNJ, I have understood how a trie works. I'm just finding it diffcult to think of its implementation in Prolog.

Comment: have you had a chance to write *any* Prolog program yet?

Comment: what do you think `new_trie(T)` query is supposed to be doing? `extend_trie([h,i],T,T2)`? `lookup_trie([h,e,y],T2)`?

Comment: @WillNess, I have, but now this difficult. I'm confused with the extend_trie, because it takes out something like this:
 T = T2, T2 = _14200-["h"-[terminal|_14244]|_14214].

Comment: don't try to comprehend a trie by looking at its raw representation, but by your interactions with it. what if you run the queries I showed you all put  into one query, with `,`s between them? what if you replace the last one with  `lookup_trie([h,i],T2)`? or with `extend_trie([h,e,y],T2,T3), lookup_trie([h,e,y],T3)`?

Comment: as a functional PL (i.e. without backtracking), Prolog is just a supercombinators SSA  (static single assignment) language with explicit state passing and modification.
"supercombinators" meaning, there is no scope, so everything you need you pass along in
predicates *arguments*, so every predicate is a supercombinator. easy.

Comment: @GuyCoder I [googled it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercombinator). :) hmm, the article is very poor. See David Turner's 1970s/80s work (SASL, KRC, Miranda), something about "compiling to supercombinators" etc. basically, turning every inner lambda function into an independent one by adding more parameters to it. then it can be "lifted" to top level.

Comment: @WillNess thank you for your comments, every word you say helps me understand more.

Comment: Still have to figure out how to add values to the nodes.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, will have to add that word ([Supercombinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercombinator))  to my vocabulary.

Comment: @Littlish (you're welcome). you shouldn't add *values* to *nodes*. you add *words* into the *trie* (supposedly with `extend_trie/3`): ["Unlike a binary search tree, *no node in the tree stores the key* associated with that node; instead, its position in the tree defines the key with which it is associated."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: another general Prolog advice is, start writing sample queries and desired output even while you don't have your definition yet. [generalize!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+%5Bprolog%5D+generalize), and you will have created it in the process!